# Launch app after internet connection check

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm making my first IOS app with cordova, now I make it check for an internet connection using the cordova plugin. If not connected it shows an alert asking to enable the connection. But when I click 'okay' and enable the connection it leaves a blank page. How can I make it relaunch when the connection is enabled, without having to close the app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the plugin to check the connnection type in your application if any connection have access then you will run your application.For the purpose you will have to use the plugin cordova-network-information .Command to install it.
`cordova plugin add cordova-network-information -save` .

-- save is to save your information config.xml file.

```
    if(navigator.connection.type!==Connection.NONE){ 
    //do nothing 
    } else {
// launch application 
}
```

here is the link to plugin [network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) further you can read there.